# Why is aria-hidden on modal always true?

Tags: php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modal.js and I see in my code that `aria-hidden="true"` when the modal is shown, this value doesn't turn to false.

Here's the part of code :

```
<a href="#document" class="btn btn-red" data-toggle="modal">
    Consulter la page des documents
</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="document" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="documentLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1 hidden="true" >This is some text</h1>
```

Then this:

```
<h1 aria-hidden="true" >This is some text</h1>
```

You'll discover that `aria-hidden` doesn't actually hide the bootstrap modal. ARIA which means Accessible Rich Internet Applications is a standard which is meant to make web applications more accessible to people with disabilities. So `aria-hidden` tells screen readers not to read out the contents of the modal.

It's javascript and CSS that hide and show the modal, not the `aria-hidden` property.

You could put your modal anywhere, for instance:

```
<div id="block1">I love to code.</div>
<div id="modal">Email: mybrother@hiswebsite.com</div><!-- YOUR MODAL -->
<div id="block2">I learnt it from my brother!</div>
<button id="modalButton">Contact my brother</button>
```

This would be just fine; but not for someone using a screen reader. That's why `aria-hidden` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

That is bug in bootstrap modal's. 
You will have manualy to change aria-hidden="false" whenever you do $("#yourID").modal("show"). To enable assistive raders like JAWS to be able to read modal content.

Like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#myModal").attr('aria-hidden', false);
});
```

and then on hidden event:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#myModal").attr('aria-hidden', true);
});
```

By definition:
aria-hidden effects:
    In supporting browsers in conjunction with supporting assistive technology the content is not conveyed to the user via the assistive technology.
    [Aria hidden documentation](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)